# Is there a way to change the Text content of TextMeshPro using Animator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

I'm using **Animator** to create an **On/Off toggle button**.

I tried to make the image change, color change, text change.

As a result, I changed the image and color, but I don't know how to change the text content.
I don't see the fields that the animator adds.

Is it impossible to change text content with an animator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no, you can not apply the effect known as **Type Writer** in Unity animation. But the code below solves your problem. The code below is a basic Type Writer effect that works by calling Coroutine. Set your `TextMeshProUGI` to the first parameter and the effect will be done.

```cs
public TextMeshProUGUI tmp;
public void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(TypeWriter("Your text here..", .2f));
}
```

```cs
public IEnumerator TypeWriter(string text, float waitTime)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        tmp.text = text.Substring(0, i);

        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(waitTime);
    }
}
```

---

### How to Add Type Writer Effect to Animator?

Here I suggest a good way to apply this effect in the animator. Click on the state you want in the animator and click `AddBehavior` for creating Type Writer Script.

[image]

[image]

Finally, all you have to do is reference the script to the OnStateEnter event. I have called the script here from my MenuManager singleton, you can also put it inside your animator character.

```cs
public class TypeWriter : StateMachineBehaviour
{
    public string text;
    public float waitTime;
    public override void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        MenuManager.singleton.StartCoroutine(TypeWriter(text, waitTime)); // reference your mono behaviour script here
    }
}
```

If you have written a script type writer inside the animator character, you can get it below. Remember to replace your script name with `Character` type on bellow, also `IEnumerator` can only be used in `mono behavior`.

```cs
public override void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
{
    animator.GetComponent<Character>().StartCoroutine(TypeWriter(text, waitTime)); // reference your mono behaviour script here
}
```